# reusing the methods of the base type in the derived custom type in golang

Tags: go

i want to create a `ReverseSort` method on `sort.IntSlice`. So i created a custom type of `MySlice` and added a method of `ReverseSort` to it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type MySlice sort.IntSlice

func (ms MySlice) ReverseSort() {
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(ms))
}
func main() {
    t2 := MySlice{5, 4, 3, 1}
    t2.ReverseSort()
    fmt.Println(t2)
}
```

But on running this program error is shown that

```
cannot use ms (type MySlice) as type sort.Interface in argument to sort.Reverse:
        MySlice does not implement sort.Interface (missing Len method)
```

Is there a way by which i can implement this without creating my own `Len` , `Swap` and `Less` methods for my custom type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could embed `sort.IntSlice` in your custom type:

```
type MySlice struct {
    sort.IntSlice
}

func (ms MySlice) ReverseSort() {
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(ms))
}

func main() {
    t2 := MySlice{sort.IntSlice{5, 4, 3, 1}}
    t2.ReverseSort()
    fmt.Println(t2)
}
```

(On [the Go Playgroud](https://play.golang.org/p/pRoZRz2pFT).)

Of course, that makes constructing objects more difficult.

---

[A post on golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/Hbxekd9g09c) discusses this:

> You "cannot define new methods on non-local type[s]," by design.
>
> The best practice is to embed the non-local type into your own own
>   local type, and extend it. Type-aliasing (type MyFoo Foo) creates a
>   type that is (more-or-less) completely distinct from the original. I'm
>   not aware of a straightforward/best-practice way to use type
>   assertions to get around that.
>
> - Peter Bourgon

And:

> > A type's methods are in the package that defines it.
>
> This is a logical coherence. It is a compilation virtue. It is seen as
>   an important benefit for large-scale maintenance and multi-person
>   development projects.
>
> The power you speak of is not lost, though, because you can embed the
>   base type in a new type as described above and add whatever you want
>   to it, in the kind of functional "is a" that you seek, with the only
>   caveat that your new type must have a new name, and all of its fields
>   and methods must be in its new package.
>
> - Michael Jones